# Openfire password forgotten - database hidden

Tags: mysql, xampp, xmpp, openfire

I have set up an openfire server two months ago and I have forgotten if I had used the built-in database or my MySQL server on localhost.

I am using Windows Server 2012 on Amazon EC2 with XAMPP (Apache & MySQL)

When I turned off my MySQL database and when i try to login to openfire web console, the web page keeps on loading and doesnt stop. That should mean that my openfire server is using MySQL. I have tried this multiple times, which confirmed that fact.

When I try to view the databases in my MySQL using the mysql console (on cmd), only two irrelevant databases are shown.

I need to know where my openfire database is, because i have lost the password.

Thanks

Vidur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to find the database configuration xml.

Copied from https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html

**Configuration**

- Stop Openfire.
- Edit conf/openfire.xml in your Openfire installation
  folder as described below using your favorite editor.
- Restart Openfire.

**Database Connection Settings**

```
<jive>
  ...
  <jdbcProvider>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <connectionString>jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?user=username&amp;password=secret</connectionString>
  </jdbcProvider>
  ...
</jive>
```

This should provide you all the info you need

Comment: Thanks helped a lot. now i know that it is hosted on mysql